# Good ways to use Crystal Reports with Salesforce?

Tags: crystal-reports, salesforce, soql

Does anyone know good ways/tools/approaches for using Crystal Reports with Salesforce.com?

I know that [Crystal Reports for Salesforce](http://www.crystalreports.com/salesforce/default.asp) exists but I'm wondering what other possibilities there are...

Comment: If you're rich enough to be using Crystal, you should pay a monetary bounty :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, we eventually decided to set up a local read-only copy of the Salesforce database in MS Sql Server, and develop reports based on that. This allowed the report-writing people to use all the familiar SQL tools they know, without the restrictions on what-can-be-joined-to-what that the native Salesforce database has.

We're using a piece of software called [DBAmp](http://www.forceamp.com/dbamp.htm) to do this - It makes Salesforce appear in SQL Server as a 'linked server', and provides stored procedures you can use to download entire Salesforce tables, or just download *changes to* a Salesforce table since the last time. This makes it very easy to set up a local copy of the data that gets updated every night.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your data is tied up with salesforce.com if you can [export data](http://community.salesforce.com/sforce/board/message?board.id=Excel_Connector&message.id=504) you could use crystal reports independent of salesforce.com.

Other links on exporting data:

- http://sfdc.arrowpointe.com/2008/04/28/do-you-backup-your-salesforce-data/
- http://ideas.salesforce.com/article/show/97976/Export_All_via_Data_Loader
- http://ideas.salesforce.com/article/show/23579/Scheduled_Data_Export_to_backup_database

Answer (score 1):

Our solution may not work for you, but we've decided to host our reports on an external reportserver which is written in c# and exposes a SOAP based web service because the Crystal Reports for Salesforce solution you mentioned didn't offer us the flexibility we needed.

The process is essentially:

1. Salesforce makes a soap based call to the report server
2. Report server collates data from Salesforce via the Salesforce Soap API
3. Report server renders the report and returns it to salesforce